# debsecan won't launch on debian wheezy

Tags: security, debian, apt

I've insalled the package debsecan in debian wheezy with 3.7.1 kernel.
when I try to run it it gives me this output:

error: while downloading http://secure-testing.debian.net/debian-secure-testing/project/debsecan/release/1/GENERIC:
error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I tried this:
adding repositories in /etc/apt/source.list
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update

But still the same result.
I'd like to be able to track down what packages I have on my debian machine and which among them are vulnerable/to be removed. 
My goal is system minimization to harden it.

Any help ?

[EDIT]
Here's the output of cat /etc/default/debsecan:

```
# Configuration file for debsecan.  Contents of this file should
# adhere to the KEY=VALUE shell syntax.  This file may be edited by
# debsecan's scripts, but your modifications are preserved.
# If true, enable daily reports, sent by email.
REPORT=true

# For better reporting, specify the correct suite here, using the code
# name (that is, "sid" instead of "unstable").
SUITE=GENERIC

# Mail address to which reports are sent.
MAILTO=root

# The URL from which vulnerability data is downloaded.  Empty for the
# built-in default.
SOURCE=
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS setup is broken. Try resolving the hostname against Google's DNS servers:

```
% host secure-testing.debian.net 8.8.8.8
secure-testing.debian.net has address 89.238.89.44
secure-testing.debian.net mail is handled by 0 alius.turmzimmer.net.
```

If this doesn't work then something is blocking your DNS requests.

Then try against your system's configured DNS servers:

```
% host secure-testing.debian.net
secure-testing.debian.net has address 89.238.89.44
secure-testing.debian.net mail is handled by 0 alius.turmzimmer.net.
```

If this doesn't work then you've got the wrong DNS servers configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you! 
Turns out my DNS was indeed broken. I added the line "nameserver 8.8.8.8" in my /etc/resolv.conf and tried out debsecan again, it failed. Here's the error message: 

error: while downloading http://secure-testing.debian.net/debian-secure-testing/project/debsecan/release/1/GENERIC:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found

**Any idea ?**

Comment: @mak That URL downloads correctly for me. There's something very weird with your network.

Comment: I can't figure out... What do you need to help me diagnose this ?

Comment: I mean, when I click the link hereabove, it downloads in my browser loke a charm ! but debsecan seems to have trouble with it...

Comment: @mak Do you have an HTTP proxy set anywhere? Check the `$http_proxy` environment variable, `/etc/apt/`, and debsecan configuration.

Comment: I did an echo `$http_proxy`, nothing. So I guess I don't have any http proxy set.
Configuration of apt and debsecan look fine to me... Here is the result of `cat /etc/default/debsecan`

Comment: I'm putting the output of the previous command in the question to have better formatting...

Comment: Ok now, I think I need to provide another piece of information to you: I'm running a Debian Image I mounted on my Ubuntu system and on which I mount my ubuntu's /proc and /dev virtual filesystems.
At first, I did not think it would change anything...
When I installed debsecan on my native ubuntu, it worked just fine. But I just won't work on the mounted image I have (a wheezy image)